# JSF Primefaces p:calendar or p:datePicker is Not showing any calendar field

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Jsf primefaces ***version 8*** and trying to show the calendar field in the xhtml page. But inspite all efforts, the popup calendar field is not displaying at all in the page.

My **main.xhtml** page contains a p:dialog and this dialog includes another xhtml page, **dateEdit.xhtml**. Inside the second xhtml, I am trying to have the `p:datePicker` or `p:calendar` field. But its not working.

Below is the piece of code from my main.xhtml page:

```
<p:dialog closable="true" visible="false" modal="true" id="dateDialog" widgetVar="dateDialog" resizable="false" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
            header="Date Edit" width="60%" height="50%" style="max-height:100%; overflow:auto; ">
            <ui:include src="dateEdit.xhtml" >
            </ui:include> 
        </p:dialog>
```

Below is the code snippet from the dateEdit.xhtml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core" >
    
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../jsfStyle.css" media="all"></link>
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
<h:body>

        <h:form id="formDtId" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >

<p:outputPanel id="editProjectInfo">
            <h:panelGrid id="coreGrid" columns="3" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="7">
<p:outputLabel for="update_Date" value="Demo&nbsp;Date : " />
                <p:calendar id="update_Date" value="#{dateManagedBean.demoDate}" mode="popup" navigator="true" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" style="font-size:8pt;" showOn="button" >
                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" for="update_Date"></f:convertDateTime>
                </p:calendar>
</h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
        
        </h:form>
        
</h:body>
</html>
```

But if I click on the button icon, no calendar is getting displayed. Nothing is happening.

[image]

I tried with the below code also, instead of p:calendar, but that also didn't work :

```
<p:datePicker id="update_Date" value="#{dateManagedBean.demoDate}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" showIcon="true" />
```

Kindly help to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript console or in your server log?

Comment: No,, no error getting in the console or log...

Comment: Are you using an old theme that might be missing CSS?  Have you tried it with the nova-light theme or one of the other built in themes?

Comment: Theme I used is a custom theme, a separate **.css** file. No built-in theme I used.